# firebase cli: database rules - how to specify the database to be applied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I am working on a project where I am creating multiple realtime databases programmatically using firebase tools(firebase CLI). I am using the following command to create a new database.

> firebase database:instances:create

. I also wanted to apply customized rules for the newly created database. I found the following command from [firebase CLI documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy)

> firebase deploy --only database

I am a little scared to use this command because nowhere I have mentioned the name of the database to be updated. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me to understand how firebase CLI picks up the database to be updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Firebase documentation on [multiple database instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding) has a section on [editing and deploying rules for each instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#edit_and_deploy_for_each_instance). I highly recommend reading that, but the gist of it is that you:

1. Define deploy targets for each shard (or set of shards) that needs to be targeted with separate rules.

   > ```
   > firebase target:apply database main my-db-1 my-db-2
   >
   > firebase target:apply database other my-other-db-3
   > ```
2. Define the rules for each target in your `firebase.json`

   > ```
   > {
   >   "database": [
   >     {"target": "main", "rules": "foo.rules.json"},
   >     {"target": "other", "rules": "bar.rules.json"}
   >   ]
   > }
   > ```
3. Deploy the rules for all targets with `firebase deploy` as usual.

Comment: `my-db-1` was confusing me because I couldn't find any reference in the docs. `my-db-1` stands for the name of the database. NOT for the URL of the database. It's a bit confusing that FB sometimes uses DB names and sometimes URLs